# WKWebview Swift 4 keeps full screening Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a swift 4 project with a web view I would like to keep the WKWebview to this size:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mKVb.png

Unfortunately the webview keeps appearing as a full screen window and is not conforming to the size.

This is the code I am using:
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate  {

```
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I use for a programmatic WKWebView to set constraints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    self.webView = webView

    if let webView = self.webView
    {
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let offset = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([height, width, offset])
    }
}
```

This varies from what you're doing in that it sets auto layout constraints.  In this case, I've got a view called contentView that's a simple UIView in my storyboard that's pinned to the superview:

[image]